# Does the Iron Bomber's projectile travel faster than the stock?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-demoman

For some reason I can't quite place my hand on, the Iron Bomber's projectile seems to travel much faster than a normal pill the stock grenade launcher.

Is this a placebo? Does the Iron Bomber's projectile travel faster than the Grenade Launcher, or is the speed still the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The projectile speed is the same.**

It is most likely that you just feel that way because the grenade from Iron Bomber bounces less than the stock Grenade Launcher.

Comment: I can confirm this in the item schema... its the same base weapon as the normal grenade launcher with only "Blast radius decreased", "grenade detonation damage penalty", "grenade no bounce", and "custom projectile model" attributes.